# how to make jquery check the last value added in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this problem, I cannot figure out how to make jquery work like I want:

- when a user goes out of a text field, jquery should get a value of the entry, then behave according to it:
  example:
  if the user enters the word 'value' in the last field, then an alert box pops up:

jquery:

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on('blur', '#list li:last-child',function(){
            if ('#list li:last-child'=='value'){
                alert('value');}
   });
});
```

and the html:

```
<form>
    <div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="firstname[]"></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="firstname[]"></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="firstname[]"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

That does not work, i am a newbie and even if it appears to you obvious, it's really not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare two string in `if ('#list li:last-child'=='value')`

Instead of that you should use `$(this).find('input').val()` to get last li input value.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on('blur', '#list li:last-child',function(){
            if ($(this).find('input').val()=='value'){
                alert('value');
             }
   });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/ZCu48/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
$(function(){
      $("input").on('blur', function(){
        if ($("#list input").last().val()=='value'){
                alert('value');}
   });
});
```